# Count number of ways to have 2 distinct cards

Tags: combinatorics

Let $$X_i$$ be the event that the $i$th card value where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $13$ is in $13$ cards. So I am trying to figure out the number of ways given 13 cards from a well-shuffled deck that $$X_i$$ and $$X_{i+1}$$ is satisfied, that is the ith value and the $i+1$th value is present in my 13 cards given to me. I know all possible ways to get 13 cards is $$52 \choose 13$$.

My approach for the numerator:
We know the ith value is present and there are 4 ways (spades, hearts, etc.) for the ith value to be present, likewise for the $i+1$ value. There are 50 choose 11 ways for the remaining cards. So in total there is $$4 * 4 * {50 \choose 11}$$ ways that the ith and $i+1$ value is present, but somehow this is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you wanna find out $Pr(X_i=m,X_{i+1}=n)$?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to find $Pr(X_i, X_{i+1})$, where $i \in (1, 2... 13)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that $4 \cdot 4 \cdot {50\choose 11}$ counts the number of ways to get the events $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ for one fixed $i$. So we would need to sum the ways to get $X_2$ and $X_3$, $X_3$ and $X_4$, and so on.

Comment: I actually am looking for a way to find it for a fixed i.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I'm afraid I don't know what's wrong with your argument :(

Comment: No worries, so they calculated this using the inclusion-exclusion. So they did $1 - P(not X_i \cup not X_{i+1}) = 1 - P(not X_i) - P(not X_{i+1}) + P(not X_i \cap not X_{i+1}$. I know that $P(not X_i) = P(not X_{i+1}) = \frac{48 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}$. And $P(not X_i \cap not X_{i+1}) = \frac{44 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}$, however this doesn't equal the answer I gave above.